# Jquery Как задать каждому блоку его текущую высоту?

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Нужно чтоб скрипт присваивал каждой колонке .col его текущую высоту! Сейчас он присваивает высоту первого блока! Подскажите что исправить, спасибо.

```js
var height = $('.col').height();
$('.col').each(function() {
  $(this).css('min-height', height);
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: во-первых, вы устанавливаете минимальную высоту, а во-вторых, вы зачем это делаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из вопроса, должно быть так:

```js
$('.col').each(function() {
  $(this).css('min-height', $(this).height());
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col {
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum</div>  
</div>
```

Но, что-то мне подсказывает, что Вам нужна высота со значением `max-content` :

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.col {
  height: max-content;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="col"> lorem ipsum</div>  
</div>
```